# GWT Failure to load module '<mymodule>'

Tags: gwt, module

When configuring a second Entrypoint  and second module in my gwt application I receive the following warning:
[WARN] Unknown module requested 'iovadmin'; all active GWT modules must be specified in the command line arguments

and the following error:
[ERROR] Unable to find 'iovadmin.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

Can someone explain me the necessary steps to correctly configure a second entrypoint in my application?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Share your project structure. You seem to have more than one gwt module and using gwt's module "inherits" tag without have the relevant source files in the GWT's Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a second EntryPoint, make sure that you have all the needed files. That is:
- In your project src/com/.../ root folder you must have your SecondEntry.gwt.xml file, with the proper  tag
- In your war/ folder you need to have the proper SecondEntry.html file
- In your war/WEB-INF/web.xml you need to have the proper servlet-mapping pointing to your second servlet.

If you have all these files, you'll need to post them to see where's the problem.